# How to import Chinese font SimSun on overleaf?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am trying to use Chinese font `simsun` on the overleaf. but it gave me an error.

Firstly, I tried this solution, but it is not working.

```
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhsong}[AutoFakeBold = {4.27}]{SimSun}
\renewcommand*{\songti}{\CJKfamily{zhsong}}
```

I also use `KaiTi` font which is working fine.

```
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhkai}[AutoFakeBold = {4.27}]{KaiTi}
\renewcommand*{\kaishu}{\CJKfamily{zhkai}}
```

Then I found out a list of the CJK Chinese fonts which are available on overleaf from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Chinese

Then I upload `SimSun.ttf` in Overleaf and import from the uploaded font.

```
\setCJKmainfont{zhsong}[AutoFakeBold = {4.27}]{SimSun.ttf}
\renewcommand*{\songti}{\CJKfamily{zhsong}}
```

But I got these errors:

`Package fontspec Error: The font "zhsong" cannot be found.`

```
‪./thesis.cls, 160‬
For immediate help type H <return>.
...                                              
                                                 
l.160 ...JKmainfont{zhsong}[AutoFakeBold = {4.27}]
                                                 {SimSun.ttf}

A font might not be found for many reasons.
Check the spelling, where the font is installed, etc. etc.
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide us with a complete (not)working example? For instance, what is `setCJKfamilyfont`?